# Mutate Time values into categorical values

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I currently have a data frame with a time stamp in character form which I converted to HMS

```
df$Time <- hms(df$Time)
```

I am trying to mutate the data set to include a categorical column with the time of day

```
ReceiptNo   Time
99          14H 53M 55S
98          14H 53M 43S
97          14H 53M 28S
96          14H 53M 8S
95          14H 52M 53S
94          14H 52M 1S
93          14H 51M 41S
92          14H 51M 15S
91          14H 51M 0S
90          14H 50M 42S
```

I've tried different variations of the following to mutate a new column with no success

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Time = case_when(
    Time <= 6 ~ "Night",
    Time <= 10 ~ "Morning",
    Time <= 14 ~ "Midday",
    Time <= 18 ~ "Afternoon",
    Time > 19 ~ "Night" ))
```

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: structure(list(ReceiptNo = c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", 
"106"), Time = new("Period", .Data = c(35, 51, 5, 26, 13, 43), 
    year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14
    ), minute = c(54, 54, 55, 55, 56, 57))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: With your statement, e.g. `hour <= 14 ~ "Midday"`, intuitively I guess it means `14:00:00` should be `Midday` and `14:00:01` should jump to `Afternoon`, right? Please clarify it. It makes Ronak's and my answers have different outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time` is of `period` class. Extract the hour from it and use it in `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(hour = Time@hour,
         Time_of_day = case_when(
                         hour <= 6 ~ "Night",
                         hour <= 10 ~ "Morning",
                         hour <= 14 ~ "Midday",
                         hour <= 18 ~ "Afternoon",
                         hour > 19 ~ "Night"))
```

Comment: Ahh I see, Ill give that a bit of a read, wasn't aware of that class. thanks!

Comment: Hi, your method converts `14H 53M 55S` to `Midday`, but with the OP's rule it should be `Afternoon`.

Comment: My method categorises the data based on hour of the day. If OP want 14 to be included as "Afternoon", I guess it's trivial to change all the values by 1? So instead of `hour <= 14` it would be `hour <= 13`.

Comment: The OP's statement is `hour <= 14 ~ "Midday"`. Intuitively I guess it means `14:00:00` should be `Midday` and `14:00:01` should jump to `Afternoon`. If you only extract the `hour` part, then `14:00:00` and `14:00:01` are always categorized into the same group. Of course it depends on the OP's thought. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The column `Time` is of the class `<Period>`, which records the number of seconds passing from `00:00:00`. You need to convert those time points into `<Period>` objects.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Time2 = case_when(
    Time <= hours(6) ~ "Night",
    Time <= hours(10) ~ "Morning",
    Time <= hours(14) ~ "Midday",
    Time <= hours(18) ~ "Afternoon",
    TRUE ~ "Night" ))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   ReceiptNo Time        Time2    
#   <chr>     <Period>    <chr>    
# 1 101       14H 54M 35S Afternoon
# 2 102       14H 54M 51S Afternoon
# 3 103       14H 55M 5S  Afternoon
# 4 104       14H 55M 26S Afternoon
# 5 105       14H 56M 13S Afternoon
# 6 106       14H 57M 43S Afternoon
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple conditions in case_when we can use cut with labels.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Time2 = cut(Time@hour, breaks = c(-Inf, 6, 10, 14, 18, Inf), 
         labels = c("Night", "Morning", "Midday", "Afternoon", "Night")))
```